# MySQL JDBC Connection fails when deployed to web server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jenkins, jdbc

I currently have a MySQL database deployed on a CentOS machine. I am able to query the database via MySQL Workbench and I can also use MySQL JDBC in a local development environment to connect to the database. Both of these connections work with no problems. However, I am building a web application that builds with Jenkins and deploys onto a Tomcat web server. However, once I deploy, the connection fails. I have no idea where I am going wrong. I've put code below but omitted password for security reasons (It is correct, I have verified multiple times). In the server logs, the error that is thrown and caught is a result of conn being null. That means that it is never being set because the parameters are incorrect. My only guess is that the the JDBC url changes when the application gets moved onto the web server.

```
enter code here//Connection for database
private static Connection conn;

//Database parameters
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://autograder.clarkson.edu:3306/autograder_db";
private String localdevuser = "autograder_dev";
private String user = "autograder_local";
private String password = "-------";

private String getUsername(){
    //LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "user is: " + (AssertionHolder.getAssertion().getPrincipal().getName())));
    //return AssertionHolder.getAssertion().getPrincipal().getName();
    return "testuser";
}

public List<Course> queryCourses(){

    //Debug statement
    LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#establishConn"));

    Connection conn = null;
    List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();

    try{            
        //create connection to database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "Conn = " + conn));
    } 
    catch (SQLException e){
        //Handle exception here
        LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#DatabaseQuery Failed: " + e.toString()));
    }
    finally {
        try{
            LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#establishConnection: DB Connection Successful"));

            //Temp course selection
            String sql = "SELECT c.course_id, c.course_title, c.course_num, c.course_descr "
                    + "FROM enrollment e LEFT JOIN courses c "
                    + "ON e.enr_cid = c.course_id WHERE e.enr_username = \"" + getUsername() + "\";";

            LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#establishConnection: String entered"));

            Statement stmt;
            LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#establishConnection: stmt"));
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#establishConnection: conn.createStatement()"));
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#establishConnection: RS"));

            while(rs.next()){
                courseList.add(new Course(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("course_id")), rs.getString("course_num"), rs.getString("course_title"), true));
                LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "Course: " + rs.getString("course_title")));
            }

            LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#establishConnection: Statement run"));

            return courseList;
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex){    
        }
    }
    return courseList;
```

Answer (score 1):

The probable cause of your error is the way you have designed your logic. You have most of the logic within the `finally` block. This is a bad idea. For example, if `DriverManager.getConnection()` fails and throws an exception, the code in the `finally` block will still execute with `conn` still being `null`, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

I'd re-structure your code to something like:

```
List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {
     String sql = ...
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
     while(rs.next()) {
         courseList.add(new Course(...));
     }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //Handle exception here
    LOG.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "#DatabaseQuery Failed: " + e.toString()));
}
return courseList;
```

Comment: I understand that my error is being caused by the Connection conn = null. However, my question is, and I suppose it isn't all that clear, is why does this code work when I compile it locally but fail when it deploys onto the web server?

Comment: No idea - there could be several reasons. Presumably an exception is thrown? If so, it looks like you log it. What is the exception and its error message? You might also want to dump the stack trace. This should give you an idea. The DB's log might also have useful info - if the connection gets that far.

Comment: Thanks for the help dave. I'll answer this question if I ever figure out what went wrong.